# I have some confusion in some custom navigation application on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios

I worked on the sample code given at http://blog.webscale.co.in/?p=150

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyTableView.h"
@interface MyTestProjectViewController : UIViewController{
    UILabel *aLabel;
    UIButton *aButton;
    MyTableView *nextView;
}

@end

@implementation MyTestProjectViewController

- (void) loadView{
    [super loadView];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    aLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 100, 200, 40)];
    aLabel.text = @"Hello World";
    [aLabel setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [aLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:aLabel];

    aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    aButton.frame = CGRectMake(125, 300, 70, 35);
    [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [aButton setTitle:@"Hit Me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:aButton];

}

- (void)buttonPressed{
    NSLog(@"button was pressed");
    if(nextView==nil)
        nextView = [[MyTableView alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextView animated:YES];
}
@end
```

in buttonPressed method i have some problem in

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextView animated:YES];
```

here `MyTestProjectViewController`.h implements `UIViewController` protocol.

It means `MyTestProjectViewController` inherits all the methods of `UIViewController` protocol. and the the line

> [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextView animated:YES];

shows that `navigationController` is the member of `MyTestProjectViewController` which is not a `UINavigationController`.
But i think `navigationController` is the member function of `UINavigationController`. Please assist me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextView animated:YES];
```

is not working because your not creating the UINavigationController object in your MyTestProjectViewController.h class
`UINavigationController *nvc`; and create property also
@property(nonatomic,retain)UINavigationController *nvc;

@synthesize in MyTestProjectViewController.m file

```
@synthesize nvc;
```

alloc the nvc in your

```
-(void)viewdidload{nvc = [[UINavigationcontroller alloc]init]}
    than use it 
[self.nvc pushViewController:nextView animated:YES];
```

it  will push to next class with above navigation bar on next class .

[self presentModalViewController:nextView animated:YES];
it will also work but you will not 
get navigation bar on top.

Comment: I know that pushViewController put the view on the navigation controller stack. my doubt is only self.navigationController. Tell me only 2 things 1. which class is pointed by self? 2.Is navigationController is the member function of class which is pointed by self?

Comment: 1>it calls to the same class in which self is written.2>YES  navigationController is the member function of class which is pointed by self if u use self.navigationcontroller.If this is wright  than accept the answer other than one can answer your question  .improve your accepting rate .

Comment: you mean MyTestProjectViewController calls the navigationController because self is written in MyTestProjectViewController class. It means it has this method. But still MyTestProjectViewController confirms to only UIViewController protocol and UIViewController does not have navigationController method. Then what is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
nextView = [[MyTableView alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyTableView" bundle:nil];
```

instead of

```
nextView = [[MyTableView alloc] init];
```

Hope it helps

edit:

```
initWithNibName:@"MyTableView" bundle:nil
```

will force the code to use MyTableView.xib

Comment: there is no problem in my program i just want to know that how is it working. In my program MyTableView implements the UINavigationController.

Comment: [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextView animated:YES]; here self points to MyProjectViewController class. But this class implements only UIViewController protocol. then how can i write self.navigationController? What is going here?

Comment: I know that pushViewController put the view on the navigation controller stack. my doubt is only self.navigationController. Tell me only 2 things 1. which class is pointed by self? 2.Is navigationController is the member function of class which is pointed by self?

Answer (score 0):

[self.`navigationController` pushViewController:nextView animated:YES];

It will not work since your application is UIViewControllerApplication. And most important UINavigationController inherits from UIViewController.

if you want to see your next view replace your's with this one

```
 [self presentModalViewController:nextView animated:YES];
```

Comment: This program is working fine. I wanted to know that how is it working.

Comment: you means viewbased application is pushing view with navigationController.

Comment: there is no problem in my program i just want to know that how is it working. In my program MyTableView implements the UINavigationController.

Comment: if navigationController is implemented then Navigation Controller contains a stack of views one over the other. you have tableview with the root of navigationController. you can push the views on the stack using pushViewController also you can pop from the stack using the popViewController.

Comment: [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextView animated:YES]; here self points to MyProjectViewController class. But this class implements only UIViewController protocol. then how can i write self.navigationController? What is going here?

Comment: yes [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextView animated:YES]; it will put the view on the navigation controller stack.

Comment: I think i am not explainly my problem correctly. I know that pushViewController put the view on the navigation controller stack. my doubt is only self.navigationController.                        Tell me only 2 things 1. which class is pointed by self? 2.Is navigationController is the member function of class which is pointed by self?

Comment: 1)  self works the same way like this pointer in c. Means it calls to the same class in which self is written.                              2) navigationController will work in all the classes you add in your project.

Comment: you mean MyTestProjectViewController calls the navigationController because self is written in MyTestProjectViewController class. It means it has this method. But still MyTestProjectViewController confirms to only UIViewController protocol and UIViewController does not have navigationController method. Then what is happening here?

Comment: I think now you can better understand my problem.